# Groovy - sort by property then by index of original list

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to sort a list first by a property and second by the original placement of the element. So

```
[[primaryProperty:2,foo:a],[primaryProperty:1,foo:c],[primaryProperty:1,foo:b]]
```

would become:

```
[[primaryProperty:1,foo:c],[primaryProperty:1,foo:b],[primaryProperty:2,foo:a]]
```

I cannot add a property (e.g."currentIndex") to the map. Is there a property like that that is part of the sort function I can use? Something like:

```
list.sort{ a, b ->
            Integer returnVal = b.primaryProperty <=> a.primaryProperty 
            if(returnVal==0) {
                return a.index <=> b.index 
            } else {
                return returnVal
            }
        }
```

I'd prefer to do this a groovy way rather than creating and sorting a wrapper if possible.

Comment: `I cannot add a property (e.g."currentIndex") to the map` - why?

Comment: It's actually an object in my code. I was just giving an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While injecteer's answer may solve the issue, repeated use of the indexOf operator would make it inefficient. I ended up making a wrapper around the list, sorting the wrapper, and then getting the data from the resulting list:

```
List wrapper = objList.withIndex().collect{ obj, index -> [obj: obj, index: index] }
wrapper.sort{ ... }
List sortedObjList = wrapper.collect{ it.obj }
```

It's not ideal as it involves the creation of a bunch of intermediary objects, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `indexOf()` in your comparator:

```
def list = [[primaryProperty:2,foo:'a'],[primaryProperty:1,foo:'c'],[primaryProperty:1,foo:'b']]

 list = list.sort{ a, b ->
            Integer returnVal = a.primaryProperty <=> b.primaryProperty 
            if(returnVal==0) {
                return list.indexOf( a ) <=> list.indexOf( b ) 
            } else {
                return returnVal
            }
        }

  assert list.toString() == '[{primaryProperty=1, foo=c}, {primaryProperty=1, foo=b}, {primaryProperty=2, foo=a}]'
```